# KVM: no support for Xeon E5

Tags: server, kernel, virtualization, intel, kvm-virtualization

I am running linux 3.13.0-71 on two Xeon E5-2603 which did, at some point, support KVM.

I had to reboot (running 3.8.0-35 before) and somehow lost all KVM support. The flags I get are:

```
fpu de tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mca cmov pat clflush acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2
ss ht syscall nx lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq monitor 
est ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave 
avx hypervisor lahf_lm arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dtherm
```

As you can see, vmx and svm are not listed.

I did a cold boot, I updated my BIOS, cleared CMOS (I was unable to verify this) and did a cold boot after (unplugged power until LEDs went out).

rdmsr 0x3a  returns "7", I do not know what that means though.

BIOS "screenshot" before bios update (looks the same now): https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyn1e.jpg

How can I get back support for KVM again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might sound a little bit stupid, but: Reason for this was that my server was running a Xen kernel. Xen does not play well (not at all) with KVM.